# R code: Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : Variable 1 has no levels

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression, glm

I am trying to build a logistic regression model with a response as diagnosis ( 2 Factor variable: B, M).
I am getting an Error on building a logistic regression model:

```
Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : 
  variable 1 has no levels
```

I am not able to figure out how to solve this issue.

R Code:

```
Cancer <- read.csv("Breast_Cancer.csv")


## Logistic Regression Model

lm.fit <- glm(diagnosis~.-id-X, data = Cancer, family = binomial)
summary(lm.fit)
```

Dataset Reference: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data

Comment: Hi Priyanshu. Could you provide some more information? For example what is the exact wording of the error you are getting? Also, could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) ? (requiring others to download a external file is not **minimal** and hardly needed to reproduce the error). Providing a mre makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is similar to the one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46465883/1335174) on the `randomForest` classifier.
Apparently `glm` checks through the variables in your data and throws an error because X contains only `NA` values.

You can fix that error by

1. either by dropping X completely from your dataset, setting `Cancer$X <- NULL` before handing it to `glm` and leaving `X` out in your formula (`glm(diagnosis~.-id, data = Cancer, family = binomial)`);
2. or by adding `na.action = na.pass` to the `glm` call (which will instruct to ignore the NA-warning, essentially) but still excluding X in the formula itself (`glm(diagnosis~.-id-X, data = Cancer, family = binomial, na.action = na.pass)`)

However, please note that still, you'd have to make sure to provide the `diagnosis` variable in a form digestible by `glm`. Meaning: either a numeric vector with values 0 and 1, a logical or a factor-vector

> "For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also be specified as a factor *(when the first level denotes failure and all others success)*" - from the [`glm`-doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/glm)

Just define `Cancer$diagnosis <- as.factor(Cancer$diagnosis)`.

On my end, this still leaves some warnings, but I think those are coming from the data or your feature selection. It clears the blocking errors :)